# space between image and cell floor

Tags: html, css

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse" border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/dGqn38/img_top.png" alt="img_top" border="0"></td>
    
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="background-color:#bd6365">
 asdh'jksadh'kd
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ggprVo/img_bottom.png" alt="img_bottom" border="0"></td>
    
  </tr>

</table>
```

[image]

hi, how do I get the image to hug the bottom of the cell? I've tried padding but it didn't work. also, why is there no space between the images and their cell ceilings but there is between their floors?

Comment: Edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To fix your code, we'll have to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `td` contents are vertically aligned to top. Add CSS to make them align to bottom.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse" border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/dGqn38/img_top.png" alt="img_top" border="0"></td>
    
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="background-color:#bd6365">
 asdh'jksadh'kd
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="full-height"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ggprVo/img_bottom.png" alt="img_bottom" border="0"></td>
    
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: this works too. so that's how u apply valign to images

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse" border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/dGqn38/img_top.png" alt="img_top" border="0"></td>
    
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="background-color:#bd6365">
 asdh'jksadh'kd
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ggprVo/img_bottom.png" alt="img_bottom" border="0" style="margin-top:4px"></td>
    
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="font-size: 0;"` on the td with bottom img

(In case you also have some text in td in future, then add the font-size specifically to that text span.)

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse" border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><img  src="https://image.ibb.co/dGqn38/img_top.png" alt="img_top" border="0"></td>
    
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="background-color:#bd6365">
 asdh'jksadh'kd
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 0;"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ggprVo/img_bottom.png" alt="img_bottom" border="0"></td>
    
  </tr>

</table>
```